# Problems converting a NaN value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nan, parseint

I'd just started learning Javascript and one of my first projects is to build a site that gets values from an input box and use them to get the area of a circle but I keep getting NaN as a result

My code looks like this:

```
let circle = document.getElementById("rCircle");
let radius = circle.value;
const calcAreaCircle = (radius) => {
    let circleResult = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    circleArea.innerHTML = ("The area is: " + circleResult)
};
```

Additional info - I have already tried converting the NaN using parseInt as `let radius = parseInt(circle.value)`. Also I keep getting NaN in the console unless the code is wrapped in a window.onload function.

Does anybody know what am I missing??

*Edit

This is part of my html

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Circles</h4>
    <div class="Figures"><img src="assets/circle-shape-outline.png" alt="Circle image"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Tell me the radius</p>
      <input type="number" name="" value="" placeholder="Raduis" id="rCircle">
      <button id="calcCircle">Get area</button>
    </div>
    <p id="circleArea"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: what is circle and element with id rCIrcle?

Comment: @Hector Can you show your HTML part also

Comment: @Misaz the element with the id rCircle is a html input tag with type=number and circle is the variable where I'm trying to store it

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: console.log(circle.value) and tell us what it is, i assume its not a number value

Comment: Do you load your script when this element is loaded in DOM? I think previous sentence is Spanish village for beginner. Easily: try to add `<script>` element Immediately before end of `<body>` element.

Comment: @Luke You are right, it says it is not s number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function check() {
    let circle = document.getElementById("rCircle");
    let circleArea = document.getElementById("circleArea");
    let radius = circle.value;
    let circleResult = Math.PI * Math.pow(parseInt(radius), 2);
    circleArea.innerHTML = ("The area is: " + circleResult)
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Circles</h4>
    <div class="Figures"><img src="assets/circle-shape-outline.png" alt="Circle image"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Tell me the radius</p>
      <input type="number" name="" value="" placeholder="Raduis" id="rCircle">
      <button id="calcCircle" onclick="check()">Get area</button>
    </div>
    <p id="circleArea"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest answer to my code, this works perfect! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parseInt with second param "null"?

```
parseInt(circle.value, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code that the input value can be get inside the function. I have modified the code and is working fine for me. You may also want to make use of number input type to avoid parsing. In case of string number, the javascript will automatically convert it into number. You can check that by removing parsing.

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<body>
Enter Value: <input type="number" id='rCircle'>&nbsp
<button onclick="calcAreaCircle()">Calculate</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="circleArea"></span>
<script>    
    var calcAreaCircle  = function(){
        var circle = document.getElementById("rCircle"),
        circleArea = document.getElementById("circleArea");
        radius = parseInt(circle.value,10);

        console.log(parseInt(circle.value,10));
        console.log(typeof radius+": "+radius);

        var circleResult = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        circleArea.innerHTML = ("The area is: " + circleResult)
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did but it's not refreshing because my account if new

Answer (score 0):

make sure, you get correct value from input with `id="rCircle"`

Answer (score 0):

As you said that your code is working fine after wrapping in `window.onload` it means that in normal case DOM loading is not finished before you called `document.getElementById("rCircle")`.

Important thing is that how you are binding your JS code. You can check the DOM loading part of your input box by this:-

```
if(document.getElementById("rCircle").length > 0)
{
    // Your JS Code like as 
    // let circle = document.getElementById("rCircle");
    // let radius = circle.value;
    // etc
}
else
{
    // DOM is not loaded , ouu need to wait for DOM loading completion
}
```

or you can call the function manually and in thac case your DOM will be finished with loading -

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Circles</h4>
    <div class="Figures"><img src="assets/circle-shape-outline.png" alt="Circle image"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Tell me the radius</p>
      <input type="number" name="" value="" placeholder="Raduis" id="rCircle">
      <button id="calcCircle" onClick="getArea()">Get area</button>
    </div>
    <p id="circleArea"></p>
</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
<script>    
    function getArea(){
        var circle = document.getElementById("rCircle"),
        circleArea = document.getElementById("circleArea");
        radius = parseInt(circle.value);
        var circleResult = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        circleArea.innerHTML = ("The area is: " + circleResult)
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hey that's a pretty clever way to check the DOM loading. Your code works perfectly on a codepen but for some reason I can't get it to work with mine. I think i'll have to rewrite it... Is it better to have the JS inside the the html or in another document??

Comment: You can write JS in a JS file and add it using script tag. Do you need any more help from my side ?

Comment: I really appreciate your help deepak but don't worry :) thanks